# Windows 8 Start screen search with touch keyboard

Tags: windows-8, search, touchscreen

On the Desktop I see the keyboard icon in the tray, but in the Start screen there is no such icon. How do I bring up the on-screen keyboard to search using touch in the Start screen?

Comment: Can you search for the keyboard, right-click and Pin to Start?

Answer (score 1):

When you swipe from the right (to bring up the Charms bar) and select the Search charm, you get a text box. Touching it should show you the OSK.

Source: [Microsoft's site about the Surface](http://www.microsoft.com/Surface/en-US/support/surface-with-windows-rt/apps-and-windows-store/start-and-close-apps). Can't test this myself since I don't own a Surface, but maybe it is of help.